# ¿Por qué "cirugía" y "quirúrgico", teniendo la misma raíz, se pronuncian diferente?

Tags: etimología, historia

Leo en la RAE el origen etimológico de las palabras `quirúrgico` y `cirugía` y veo que son el mismo:

> **[quirúrgico, ca.](http://dle.rae.es/quir%C3%BArgico)**
>
> (Del lat. chirurgĭcus, y este del gr. χειρουργικός).
>
> **[cirugía.](http://dle.rae.es/cirug%C3%ADa)**
>
> (Del lat. chirurgĭa, y este del gr. χειρουργία).

Entonces, ¿por qué en un caso usamos el sonido `"k"` y en otro el sonido `"c"`? Es decir, ¿por qué no tenemos `"cirúrgico"` y `"cirugía"` o `"quirúrgico"` y `"quirugía"`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Existe un proceso de cambio fonológico que se llama **lenición**, que consiste en que dadas algunas circunstancias las consonantes fuertes se debilitan. (Por ejemplo, en mi país Chile es muy frecuente que se relaje la [ch] y se diga *anoshe escushé una sharla*).

Durante la formación del español ocurrió la lenición de algunas consonantes. La más habitual consiste en que las consonantes sordas se sonorizaron, como en la palabra *apoteka* que derivó al español *bodega*.

Pero hubo otras formas de lenición. En el caso de esta pregunta, la [k] dejó de ser oclusiva (o sea dejó de interrumpir violentamente el paso del aire en el paladar) y se convirtió en fricativa (o sea, se empezó a dejar pasar el aire "raspando", probablemente con un sonido cercano a las actuales [j], [g] o [ch]).

En un proceso posterior (s. XVI y XVII) varias de esas fricativas se convirtieron en sibilantes, nuestras actuales [c] y [s]. De ese modo, algunas palabras que originalmente se pronunciaban con [k] llegaron a pronunciarse con [c] o [s] y en Latinoamérica sólo con [s]. Por ejemplo:

> latín **caelum** > cielo
>
> griego **kenós** + phobos > cenofóbia (temor a los lugares vacíos)
>
> latín **centum** (se pronuncia kentum) > cien

Llegados a este punto ya sabemos cómo el latín **khirurgia** (se pronuncia *kirúrgia*) evolucionó a **cirugía**.

Bueno, ocurre que es muy normal que convivan en el léxico distintas formas de la misma palabra, que evolucionan a distinto ritmo. Una forma se pronuncia tratando de respetar la palabra original, por ejemplo cuando se trata de conceptos técnicos o científicos, o cuando forman parte de lenguajes ritualizados. Y la otra forma evoluciona normalmente, por ejemplo cuando es más cercana al habla doméstica. Aunque en realidad la preferencia de una u otra finalmente se debe a los caprichos de la comunidad lingüística.

Por ejemplo, a partir de la misma palabra *apoteka* derivaron las palabras *botica* y *bodega*.

Eso es lo que ocurre con **quirúrgico** y **cirujano**. Ambas formas derivan de la misma raíz, pero la primera se mantiene más apegada al latín.

(Por cierto, la palabra griega original es *jeirourgeia*, se pronuncia más o menos *chirurgia* y significa "trabajo manual").

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Abrí el "bounty" (recompensa) para dar las gracias a Blas Soriano por su gran respuesta. Qué alegría que la respuesta se haya mejorado aún más con la tuya. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Qué bien , gracias :)

Answer (score 15):

En la mayoría de las palabras procedentes del griego χειρ (mano) el sonido se traduce habitualmente como *kir*; así es con las palabras quirófano, quiromancia, quiropráctica, quiróptero...

En el caso de la palabra cirujano se produce una excepción, probablemente debido a que la palabra fue originalmente introducida en un ambiente popular (a diferencia del ambiente culto); en este caso, se palatalizó el sonido como *cir*, a semejanza de algunas palabras derivadas del latín como las derivadas de círculo, del latín *circulus*, diminutivo de *circus* (cerco), y este del griego antiguo *κίρκος*.

Comment: Qué explicación tan buena. Muchas gracias por ella.

Answer (score 4):

Para poder entender estas diferentes pronunciaciones, que son muy normales en el español, debemos comprender que hay vocales débiles y vocales fuertes. Las débiles son: "i" , "u". Las vocales fuertes: "a", "e", "o". Con las vocales fuertes el sonido de la letra "c" suena como "k", en cambio, con las vocales débiles el sonido "k" no se mantiene y se traslada a un sonido fricativo como el de "c". Entonces, entendiendo esto, se puede saber que en la palabra "cirugía" la pronunciación va a ser fricativa. Ahora, por qué no es "cirúrgico". Gramaticalmente para poder igualar el sonido "k" en las vocales débiles se utiliza "qu" ("quirúrgico").

Esto es algo que pasa con todas las palabras que tengan una sílaba "ca", "ce", "ci", "co", "cu". Por ejemplo: *Pla**ce**ntero*, *Pa**ci**en**ci**a*, *vo**caci**ón*.
Si en estas palabras quisiera cambiarse el sonido de las vocales débiles por uno como el de "k" tendrían que escribirse así: *"Pla**quen**tero"*, perdiendo absolutamente su significado.

Hay que entender también que los cambios en la lengua española (mayoritariamente en América Latina), sobre todo en el área fonológica, han echo que las palabras vayan tomando otras pronunciaciones, por ende, independiente si provienen de la misma raíz, el hablante a través del tiempo busca la comodidad y la economía al hablar, claramente sin perder la función comunicativa principal que es la comprensión de lo que se dice para una comunicación clara y fluida.

En español (hablando desde Chile en este caso), estas dos palabras cumplen con ser sinónimas, que se pueden usar en variados contextos, ambas reemplazables una de la otra, pero dentro de un contexto que sea adecuado y no pierdan las mismas características.