# ¿Por qué hay c, k y q? ¿Es que alguna vez se pronunciaron distinto?

Tags: ortografía, historia, letras

En español hacemos tres dibujos distintos (**c**, **k** y **qu**) para representar un mismo sonido (que, según acabo de ver, es el *oclusivo velar sordo* /k/).

¿Cómo llegamos a este estado tan confuso y poco económico? De la k me imagino que nos llegó hace poco desde afuera, pero la c y la q están muy metidas en el sistema. Si "cama" y "quema" se diferencian sólo en una vocal, ¿por qué la diferencia ortográfica en una consonante cuyo sonido no cambia? ¿Es que antes correspondían a sonidos distintos que finalmente se redujeron a uno solo?

Comment: relacionado: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16783/why-are-ks-translated-as-cs-in-some-scientific-terms/16786

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En resumidas cuentas, esto es una herencia del latín, de donde procede nuestro alfabeto y nuestra lengua.

En latín arcaico se usaban *k* y *c* en distintos contextos ortográficos, aunque se pronunciaban igual (oclusiva velar sorda /k/). Viendo esta redundancia y siendo más inteligentes que nosotros, descartaron la *k* y se quedaron solo con [la *c* (que en latín se leía siempre /k/)](https://www.delcastellano.com/errores-pronunciacion-latin/). La *k* permaneció para unos pocos arcaísmos como *kalendae* y poco más.

La grafía *qu* sí representaba un sonido distinto, la oclusia labiovelar sorda /kʷ/ (que no es lo mismo que /kw/, que son dos fonemas seguidos). En la evolución del latín al español, nuestra lengua perdió la coarticulación labial (la ʷ, vaya) y por tanto se fusionó con la antigua /k/. El hecho de que sigamos distinguiendo las grafías *c* (y *k*) y *qu* no es más que mero *respeto a la etimología*.

Comment: Como acotación, el latín mantuvo la ortografía con _k_ para voces de origen griego, y así también lo hizo el castellano más tarde, con la excepción de algunas palabras muy naturalizadas en el habla.

Comment: En latín arcaico la grafía < *C* > podía sonar /k/ o /g/ . Está documentado que la grafía < *G* > fue inventada por Espurio Carvilio Ruga: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurius_Carvilius_Ruga en el siglo III a.C.